# consuming memory by script on server

Tags: php, file-upload, memory-limit

Image manipulation after file-uploading causes this error:

> Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   20624 bytes) in .. on line 61

Line 61 is:

```
$imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($plik);
```

On server memory limit is set on 32MB.

I wrote code like this:

```
<?php
$user   = $_POST['user_name'];
   $pass  = $_POST['pass'];
   $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


   if ($user == "myuser" && $pass == "mypassword")
   {

    $directory='grafika/small'; 
    $dir=opendir($directory);
    $U = 1;
    while($file_name=readdir($dir))
    {
         if(($file_name!=".")&&($file_name!=".."))
        {
        $U += 1;
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);

    //------------------

    //------   

       list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
       $new_height_d = 600;
       $percent_d = $height / 600;
       $new_width_d = $width / $percent_d;
      if ($new_width_d > 1100){
          $percent = $new_width_d / 1100;
          $new_width_d = 1100;
          $new_height_d = $new_height_d/ $percent;

      }


       $percent_m =  $height / 113;
       $new_width_m = $width / $percent_m;

       $image_d = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width_d, $new_height_d);
       $image_m = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width_m, 113);

       $imaged = imagecreatefromjpeg($plik);
       $imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($plik);

       imagecopyresampled($image_d, $imaged, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width_d, $new_height_d, $width, $height);
       imagejpeg($image_d,'grafika/big/'.$U.'.JPG');
       imagecopyresampled($image_m, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width_m, 113, $width, $height);
       imagejpeg($image_m,'grafika/small/'.$U.'.JPG');
    //--------------------


    //


        $do_zapis =' <img class="mini" src="./grafika/small/'.$U.'.JPG" onClick="wys_big(\''.$U.'\')" alt="zaklin"/>';
        $file = "subpages/min_lista.html";
        $f = fopen($file, "a"); 
        flock($f, 2); 
        fwrite($f, $do_zapis); 
        flock($f, 3); 
        fclose($f);
    //-------------   


       echo('ok');

   }
   else{
       echo('not ok');

   }
   header("Refresh: 2; URL=edycja.php");
?>
```

And when i try to run it on server, uploading *.jpg file(less than 1MB) the error appears (see above).

So i'm thinking is there any way to reduce consumed memory or maybe this is normal?

Comment: 1. Which code will be executed around line 61? 2. Memory consumption also depends on image size.

Comment: The funny thing is, after you fixed your memory problem, you will have a problem when two files are submitted in parallel as they might get the same number. And please only post line 61 and round of your code, so it's easier to see where actually the memory limit is triggered.

Comment: I would advise staying switching the 2nd argument of `flock()` to the pre-defined constants. They're more descriptive. So they would be `flock($f, LOCK_EX)` and `flock($f, LOCK_UN)` for the first and 2nd instances respectively.

Comment: hakre it won't be the problem, this script will be used only by one person, Tarek- i guess it wont fix my memorry problem:) but i change it. Here it is 61' line (image's weight is always below 1,1 MG) >>61  $imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($plik);
>>62  imagecopyresampled($image_d, $imaged, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width_d, $new_height_d, $width, $height);

Comment: How large is the image `$plik` (*pixel* size width and height)?

Comment: @radek: I edited your question to put the most important information upfront.

Answer (score 2):

You're just hitting a memory limit. Increase the memory limit (e.g. 256MB for image manipulation) and the problem should be gone.

Check your PHP.ini or raise the limit before you start with image manipulation:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "256m -- 256 megabytes for image manipulation -- m");
```

Comment: I wont answer this myself and steal your thunder, but will add the code: `ini_set("memory_limit", "100M");` (this should be added at the very top of your image manipulation class)

Comment: @Kalle H. Väravas: You can't steal my answer ;), but I don't want to hinder you from answering, so please feel free.

Comment: Na, your answer is golden. But my experience shows, that the memory_limit helps only a little. If you have an issues with exhausted memory, then you should revise your code :)

Comment: @Kalle H. Väravas: Well it depends. Sometimes you just need memory and changing the code won't help. If the code is badly written however, you're totally right, then even more memory does not help any more ;)

Comment: Word! For my at least, the stats is that in more cases, the issue is in the code. Like example: Get original image -> Rotate -> Resize -> Crop -> Generate thumbnail etc.. You can actually merge all these functions in a neater way. Cant remember how, but I solved my problem without the use of memory_limit ^^